# Extend List using JS Link with HighCharts

Tags: list-view, jslink

In a list view I want to override a value with a small chart with HighCharts...

The Basic idea: Render the highchart into the jquery container and then return the HTML code:

```
    (function(){
    var Resports = {};

    Resports.Templates = {
        Fields: {
            "Report": { "View": pieChart },
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(Resports);

})();

function pieChart(ctxOBJ) {
    valueSTR = ctxOBJ.CurrentItem[ctxOBJ.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

    chartsConfigJSON = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [valueSTR]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5]
            }]
        }
    containerOBJ = $('<div>');
    containerOBJ.highcharts(chartsConfigJSON);

    return containerOBJ();
}
```

But high charts just renders the empty diagram without the actual bars.

I guess that it needs an existing container that is already attached to the DOM tree, because it wants to animate the bars in real time.

Is there a way to force highcharts to use a JQuery object that is not attached to the DOM?

thx
-Dave

Here is an update (does not work on a grouped view, where it just rederes the last group in the list):

```
(function(){

    var Reports = {};
    Reports.Templates = {
        Fields: {
            "OEE": { "View": preRenderValue },
            "Yield": { "View": preRenderValue },
            "Availabilty": { "View": preRenderValue },
            "Performance": { "View": preRenderValue },
        }
    };

    Reports.OnPostRender = pieChart;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(Reports);
})();

function preRenderValue(ctxOBJ) {
    valueSTR = ctxOBJ.CurrentItem[ctxOBJ.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    containerJQR = $('<div class="chartContainer" style="width:40px; height:40px">');
    containerJQR.text(valueSTR);
    //idINT = ctxOBJ.CurrentItem.Id;
    return containerJQR.prop('outerHTML');
}

function pieChart(ctxOBJ) {
    //ctxOBJ.CurrentItem;

    $('.chartContainer').each(function(){       
        var valueFLT = $(this).text() * 100;
        var invertFLT = (100 - valueFLT);
        //console.log($(this).text() + ": " + valueFLT + '|' + invertFLT);

        //chartsDataJSN = [valueFLT, invertFLT];
        chartsConfigJSON.colors = ['#' + getColor(valueFLT), '#F5F5F5'];
        chartsConfigJSON.series = [{
            data: [valueFLT, invertFLT],
        }];

        $(this).highcharts(chartsConfigJSON);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can force Highcharts to use something that is not already attached to the DOM, but what you can do is use the rendering cycle to set yourself up a placeholder in the DOM, and then put off using Highcharts until the DOM is ready by calling it from `OnPostRender`.

Something like:

```
// set up a place to store data that can be accesed 
// from various different function scopes
var MyNameSpace = MyNameSpace || {};

(function () {
    var Resports = {};

    Resports.Templates = {
        Fields: {
            "Report": { "View": setUpDiv },
        }
    };
    Resports.OnPostRender = pieChart;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(Resports);

})();

function setUpDiv (ctxOBJ) {
    // store whatever data we will need later
    MyNameSpace.DataINeedLater = ctxOBJ.CurrentItem[ctxOBJ.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

    // set up a placeholder to use later
    return '<div id="chartHolder"></div>';
}

// this is now called from OnPostRender
// so the DOM will be available
function pieChart() {

    chartsConfigJSON = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [MyNameSpace.DataINeedLater]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5]
        }]
    }

    containerOBJ = $('div#chartHolder');
    containerOBJ.highcharts(chartsConfigJSON);
}
```

Comment: I tried that already... the problem is, that the postRender function will be called severall time when using a grouped view and then it only renders one of the charts...
But probably the only possible way...

Comment: Oh I got it... had to remove the CSS class, to prevent JQuery to overwrite the already rendered containers...